# Installing GitLab on CentOS 6.5: Curl error

Tags: curl, centos, gitlab

I'm newbie to GitLab and CentOS.
I'm trying to install GitLab on CentOS 6.5 using below offical link:
https://about.gitlab.com/downloads/#centos6

While executing below step:

```
curl -sS https://packages.gitlab.com/install/repositories/gitlab/gitlab-ce/script.rpm.sh | sudo bash
```

I'm getting following errors:

```
Detected operating system as centos/6.
Checking for curl...
Detected curl...
Downloading repository file: https://packages.gitlab.com/install/repositories/gitlab/gitlab-ce/config_file.repo?os=centos&dist=6&source=script
curl: (6) Couldn't resolve host 'packages.gitlab.com'

Unable to run:
    curl https://packages.gitlab.com/install/repositories/gitlab/gitlab-ce/config_file.repo?os=centos&dist=6&source=script

Double check your curl installation and try again.
```

I also tried curl command with proxy settings, still getting same error.
Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Workaround is to just download the package and install it. That bash script is only determining your operating system and then downloading and installing the appropriate package. You can surely do this yourself if you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was facing two issues while installing GitLab on CentOS:

1) **proxy issues**: The error message read:

```
Couldn't resolve host 'packages.gitlab.com'
```

So I setup the https proxy as below

```
export https_proxy=username:password@proxy:port
```

2) **root authority issues**: Since I was installing GitLab through a non-root user and GitLab was installing packages under /etc/repos.d which was under ownership of root user, the installation failed. Hence I looged-in through root and installed it.

Thanks!